# Printing massive number of files into pdf

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ubuntu

Hey guys I need to print a project that I wrote in C to PDF format, 
The problem is that I have a lot of files that sit in different directories and I don't want to print it one by one using Ubuntu text editor.

I did a little research and found that I need to use lpr shell commend with cat(recursively) but I don't understand how to use it to print to PDF.

can any1 help me?

edit1:

when I try to do something like cat * | lpr - P PDF 
I'm getting the next error: lpr: The printer or class does not exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could install cups-pdf  then do

cat filename.c | lpr -P PDF

this  puts  a pdf file  in your  ~/PDF

Answer (score 1):

Try [a2ps](http://www.gnu.org/s/a2ps/).

> GNU a2ps is an Any to PostScript filter. Of course it processes plain text files, but also pretty prints quite a few popular languages.

Answer (score 1):

You could also look at the `enscript` program.